# async Task<T>() not returning straight away when not using await

Tags: c#, async-await, task, configureawait

If I have the following function

```
public async Task<bool> Foo()
{
  // call many async functions
  await Bar1().ConfigureAwait(false);
  await Bar2().ConfigureAwait(false);
  return await Bar3().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

If I call the function above

```
var t1 = Foo();
var t2 = Foo();
...
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

t2 will not execute until t1 completes, (so calling `WaitAll` is a bit pointless).

But if I call

```
...
var t1 = Task.Run( async () => await Foo().ConfigureAwait(false));
var t2 = Task.Run( async () => await Foo().ConfigureAwait(false));
...
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

t1 and t2 return immediately...

And now if I run ...

```
...
var t1 = Task.Run( () => Foo());
var t2 = Task.Run( () => Foo());
...
await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

t1 and t2 also return immediately...

Why does Foo() not return task immediately?

And, should I call `Task.Run( () => Foo())` or `Task.Run( async () => await Foo().ConfigureAwait(false))`

Comment: how are you verifying those results? do you print to stdout or?

Comment: Yes, I print to console when `t1` start/complete, `t2` start/completes and when `WaitAll` starts/complete. Those are long running functions, so there is no way that `t1` complete before `t2` starts

Comment: "t2 will not execute until t1 completes" -- t2 should execute as soon as t1 is first interrupted. If it is never interrupted, that suggests you don't actually have any async code in `Bar1`/`Bar2`/`Bar3`. Is that correct?

Comment: Hum, no, I have a few async code inside that function, (between 3 and 5). Those are database calls (Sqlite .NET).

Comment: i believe in your final sample case you are actually starting two tasks that each start a Foo() task, there is no awaiter, the initial two task runs would complete almost immediately. The Foo() tasks they start would exhibit the same behavior internally with or without `Task.Run` being used but your `WhenAll` isn't observing the Foo() Tasks.

Comment: i believe in your second to last case, you have a lamba with async/await which last i checked does not cause an wait on the Task scheduled via Task.Run (it does, however, allow awaits internal to the tasks that are started, which is itself useful.)

Comment: in the default case, i believe you are actually waiting for the default TaskScheduler to schedule work. You may observe that tasks are being run synchronously, and are not being scheduled asynchronously unless some task execution delay is observed by the default [TaskScheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskScheduler.cs,4f402907aab72487,references

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs,263

If you suspect its a problem with the task scheduler, implementing a "dummy" scheduler to confirm/deny it's scheduler behavior is pretty easy to do.

Comment: There are code fragments here but I still found it hard to follow exactly what you're saying (my misreading led to my earlier deleted answer). We could really do with having a [mcve] that we can play around with ourselves to observe the behaviour.